# How can I determine the range of the graph $\arccos(1/x^2)$

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

**EDIT:** All that is required for me to understand how to graph the function, is how to determine its range

---

As the title implies, I am unsure of how to  graph $\arccos(1/x^2)$. So far, I have found that there is an asymptote at $x=0$, and the domain is $x \ge 1$ and $x \le-1$, and that the range is $0 \le y \le \pi$, and that the function is even.

I had a pretty good idea of the graph until I plotted it onto the Desmos website, and realised that there is no asymptotic nature of $x=0$, and the range is different. Can someone please explain why this is so?

This is quite urgent, so any quick help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't learnt anything about imaginary numbers yet. Is there an approach to this question which is not too advanced?

Comment: If the domain is $x\leq-1 \vee x\ge1$, how can there be an asymptote at $x=0$? Hint: definition of an asymptote.

Comment: Oh, so since it is restricted to that domain, it cannot tend towards $x=0$? I understand that now, but I don't understand why the range is $0≤y≤π/2$

Comment: Is anyone able to help?

Comment: To understand the range: Think of $y = \arccos (x)$ as $ \cos y = x$ in your case this is $\cos y = (1/x^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You have correctly identified the domain of the function, and also the fact that the range of $\arccos\theta$ is $[0,\pi]$. But for the domain you have found, what is the sign of the argument of $\arccos$? What does the fact that the argument is always positive tell you about the value of $\arccos\frac{1}{x^2}$ and therefore about the range of your function?

Comment: I'm still not sure what to do. Does it have something to do with what occurs when x tends to positive or negative infinity?

Comment: As $x$ ranges from $1$ to $\infty$, or from $-1$ to $-\infty$, what happens to $\frac{1}{x^2}$?